Allow the new key to be trusted on Android devices by uploading proof-of-rotation
How to generate proof-of-rotation file ?I need to generate this file 
Google Play manage your app signing key
I'm doing app siging as I lost my previous jks file and now need to update app. I have complete all other steps, now I'm stuck in this last step for creating "generate proof-of-rotation file".
Please help me with this.
Thank you
